# What are examples that will further explain the relationship of density to mass and volume, when mass is uniformly distributed?

Tags: mass, density, volume

Examples that will further explain the relationship of density to mass and volume, when mass is uniformly distributed.

Answer (score 1):

I often use it while cooking. If I need a certain volume of liquid in my recipe, be it either water, milk or whatever else. I will use a scale, and with the correct density, I know which volume I have based on what the scale reads. Measuring weight (mass) this way, is more accurate than measuring volume with a cup.